# FTPing inside of a KSH script from AIX to Windows to GET a file

Tags: windows, get, ftp, ksh, aix

```
#!/bin/ksh
 . $HOME/bin/init.ksh
# log_start
 exit_if_not_dgftp

# EXPIRE_DAYS=30

# create_arc_dir
# handle_error abort $? "Command create_arc_dir failed" $USER

# purge_archive $EXPIRE_DAYS

WORK_FILE=RetriesExceeded.csv
USER=LawsonIT-FinMM@test.org
HOST=lawsonfax.test.org

# Ftp the file
# Ftp username and password is in .netrc

$FTP -v $HOST
lcd $WORK_FILE
get RetriesExceeded.csv
quit

# archive_file $WORK_FILE

# /law/bin/mpack -s "Fax Retries Exceeded" $WORK_FILE_OUTPUT $USER

# log_stop
exit 0


[dgftp@lawapp2]/lawif/bin$ get_lawson_fax.ksh
Connected to lawsonfax
220 Microsoft FTP Service
331 Password required for dgftp.
230 User logged in.
ftp> quit
221 Goodbye.
/lawif/bin/get_lawson_fax.ksh[33]: lcd:  not found
/lawif/bin/get_lawson_fax.ksh[34]: get:  not found
/lawif/bin/get_lawson_fax.ksh[35]: quit:  not found
[dgftp@lawapp2]/lawif/bin$
```

Explanation: The script connects fine to the lawson fax server, but stops at a FTP prompt.  I can type in 'Get' interactively and it works, but in a KSH script it just stops at ftp prompt and then when I quit it gives three not found errors.  If I am on the AIX server and manually FTP, open lawsonfax, get retriesexceed.csv there is no issue pulling the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using shell-redirection:

```
ftp -v "$HOST" <<DONE
lcd $WORK_FILE
get RetriesExceeded.csv
quit
DONE
```

Comment: #!/bin/ksh
. $HOME/bin/init.ksh
log_start
exit_if_not_dgftp

EXPIRE_DAYS=30

create_arc_dir
handle_error abort $? "Command create_arc_dir failed" $USER

purge_archive $EXPIRE_DAYS

WORK_FILE=RetriesExceeded.csv
MAIL="test@test.org"
HOST=lawsonfax

# Ftp the file
# Ftp username and password is in .netrc

$FTP -v "$HOST" << EOF

get RetriesExceeded.csv
quit
EOF

archive_file $WORK_FILE

CMD="/law/bin/mpack -s 'RetriesExceeded.csv' $WORK_FILE $MAIL"

log_stop

Comment: Its working great now, but the mpack command to email is not working.

Comment: You cannot paste code into a comment. Do open a new question. Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve